# HTML height and background image issue

Tags: html, css

I have a container div, inside content and footer like this

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class='leveln'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2014</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have given 100% height to body.For 'leveln' class, I have a backgroundimage.

```
.leveln{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('/resources/img/head/f3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

The problem is background image is not coming in ie without giving height for container.
But if I give height for container, my footer is not going down when I add content via ajax to container.

```
overflow:auto is working.
```

But it is showing unnecessary scrollbars.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give some jsfiddle demo?

Comment: what the last </div> close?

Comment: sorry..I corrected it.

Comment: The height is undetermined at rendering time. If you want your page looks like an app, consider using js to add fixed width in pixels according to view/current window height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it may help you to apply the css rule over the html tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
       <style>
       .maincontainer {
           width:100%;
           height:768px;
           position:relative;
           margin:0px auto;
           background:hsla(0,0%,100%,1)
       }
       .container {/* At first you have to set the main container rule.You have to set the minimun property to 
       call the child div .If you do it you will be able to see the image*/
           width:600px;
           height:350px;
           margin:0px auto;
           position:relative;
           box-shadow: 0 0 18px #3D2828;
           border-radius:10px;
           bottom:50px;
           top:30px;
       }
        .leveln{
            width: 590px;
            height: 345px;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            position: relative;
            background-image: url(../Images/Car/lotus_concept_car-wide.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            border-radius:10px;
            border:3px solid #c5fc3f;

        }
        .footer {
            width:100%;
            height:150px;
            margin:0px auto;
            border:3px solid #CCC;
            border-radius:10px;
            position:relative;  
            top:265px;          
        }
        .footer>p {
            color: #006699;
            font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',Geneva,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            height: 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 126px;
            width: 200px;
        }
       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="maincontainer">

            <div class="container">
                    <div class='leveln'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                          <p>Copyright &copy; 2014</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]